# Crash with no error wrote in console on UISplitView leftview 3rd or 4th selection (very strange)

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have a strange issue on my iPad app (an upgrade of an iPhone app).

Key facts:
- It's a UISplitVIew based application.
- The LeftView is a NavigationController.
- The RightVIew (detailView) is also a NavigationController
- When the user select a row in the RootView of the LeftView I push a new tableview, when the user select a row in this second tableview I update the detailView by reloading the lists of data I need and by calling [tableview reloadData].

The issue consist of this:
When the user select a row (whatever) in the second tableview (leftview) the detailview is updated cocrrectly, when the user select another row (whatever) the detailview is updated correctly, when the user select a third row (whatever) the app crash without logging anything on the console.

Insted, if the user select a row (whatever) in the second tableview (leftview) and then return to the rootview, select a row to push the second tableview and select a row and then return to the rootview and so on the app never crashes.

I'm going crazy, Could be a memory leak problem?

(I hope that my explanation it's clear, I'm italian and my english it's not so well)

Thank you very much.
Daniele.

Comment: Nothing is logged at all, not even EXC_BAD_ACCESS?

Comment: Nothing except this:
2010-11-06 00:50:08.931 MyiPadApp[29373:207] Reachability Flag Status: -R ------- networkStatusForFlags
If I debug the only thing that I see in the stack is:
objc_msgSend
??
-[UITableView(UITableViewInternal)_createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:]

Comment: ops I have just noticed that when I debug EXC_BAD_ACCESS is logged. But what it means?

Answer (score 0):

objc_msgSend() is the c function wherein your method call is executed by the ObjC runtime.  When you see EXC_BAD_ACCESS coming up in obj_msgSend(), it means that the object you were calling a method on in the previous frame of the stack isn't valid.  Most likely, it has already been deallocated.

You have a problem with your memory management of the object in question.  The crash is happening in a call to -[UITableView(UITableViewInternal)_createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:], which is an internal method of UITableView.  Presumably, this method if being called on a UITableView that has already been deallocated.  You should look in the backtrace to determine which of your table views is the one that has been deallocated, and then review your memory management for that object.  You're probably over-releasing it, or not retaining it when you should be.